# How to put HTML into Slickgrid cell?

Tags: javascript, slickgrid

When I put `<a href="#">Click</a>` into slickgrid, I see the actual code "`<a href="#">Click</a>`", whereas I expect the link to be rendered.

I know I can do it by subscribing click event but is it restricted thing in SlickGrid?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Write a custom formatter:

```
function myFormatter(row, cell, value, columnDef, dataContext) {
  return "<a href='#'>Click</a>";
}
```

and specify it in the column definition.

Comment: Or use the defaultFormatter option to treat any value as HTML:
`
defaultFormatter: function (row, cell, value, columnDef, dataContext) {
  if (value == null) return '';
  return value.toString();
}
`

Answer (score 6):

From @RicardoStuven

> Or use the defaultFormatter option to treat any value as HTML:

```
defaultFormatter: function (row, cell, value, columnDef, dataContext) { 
    if (value == null) return ''; 

     return value.toString(); 
}
```